The solidify modifier is getting weird affects from material displacement (bump and displacement turned on)
I'm getting weird edge details on my shape after applying a displacement node to the material output of the shader (notice the little appendage appearing on the left side in the first image). I imagine its the solidify modifier, but I'd love to find a non destructive solution so I can continue to copy the modifiers I'm using over to any new UI elements I want to add in the scene.
Does anyone have any ideas? Would greatly appreciate it.
The object stared as an image as plane, with a single subdivide. Then I stacked a corner bevel, solidify, and bevel edge to it. The displacement comes from the image too, just converted to black and white.
—————————
EDIT 5.31:  Adding a labled example of the glitch I'm trying to get rid of.


—————————





Generally speaking, the Bevel mod and displacement/ hi-res meshes don't work well together. Bevel is for rounding sharp corners of hard-surface objects - generally objects with limited geometry. If you want to smooth corners of a displaced mesh I would try the Smooth mod.

Additionally, using a plain-old JPEG with compression artefacts and low bit depth is going to cause problems with displacement and normals. Height maps are usually 16bit at the very least because lower bit depths can cause stepping issues. I don't know for certain this is your problem but it could be the case.

Thanks @Jakemoyo

D'oh, lost edit access on my comment.... trying again!
Thanks @Jakemoyo. Though feel like I got pretty good results before adding the bump map displacement. I was hoping there was a way to eliminate the weird latch/aberration that appears on the side of the floating button.
I'm not too worried about the artifacting from the bump, (but will add bit depth and resolution to my psds, great idea) at the moment, usually I just crank up subdivisions to fix that...
I'm going to try to add some example images to the post
